# Почему не выводится класс при наведении?

Tags: html, css

В коде указано, что когда навожу на ссылку, должен появляться класс. Но код не работает, хотя когда ставлю в CSS наведение на целый класс .callback, а не на отдельную ссылку, то всё нормально. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на ссылку выводился .city-menu?

```css
.callback {
    position: relative;
}

.city-menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
  
}

.callback a:hover .city-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="callback"><p>Ваш город:
                            
                                <br><a href="#">Киев</a>
                                    <div class="city-menu">
                                      <ul>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div>
                                
                                
                            </p></div>
```

Comment: Вам поможет cелектор следующего элемента `~`

Answer (score 0):

Вы вешаете hover на класс .callback + линк , но в вашем html, внутри етого класса сначало идет p, а потом ссылка. Вам надо добавить .callback p a, или сделать как в примере ниже.А в общем никто не пихает в p все сразу и ссылки,списки,блоки.Сделайте нормальную структуру!

```css
.callback {
    position: relative;
}

.city-menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
  
}

.callback:hover .city-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="callback"><p>Ваш город:
                            
                                <br><a href="#">Киев</a>
                                    <div class="city-menu">
                                      <ul>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div>
                                
                                
                            </p></div>
```

Comment: Поправил структуру, сделав отдельно параграф и снизу ссылку, однако всё равно ничего не работает. Повторюсь, мне не нужно, чтобы при наведении на класс выводился другой класс, мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на ссылку выводился нужный класс.

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы хотите, в моем примере когда вы наводите на ваш город Киев, выводиться список!Как вам надо?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере две ошибки:

1) тег `p` автоматически закрывается перед следующим блочным элементом. В данном случае перед `<div class="city-menu">`.

В инспекторе браузера можно увидеть следующую структуру

```
<div class="callback">
    <p>Ваш город:
        <br>
        <a href="#">Киев</a>
    </p>
    <div class="city-menu">
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Такой селектор `.callback a:hover .city-menu` выбирает теги с классом `city-menu`, которые находятся внутри тега `a` на который наведен курсор. В данной разметке нет подходящих условий.

Вот вариант решения проблемы:

```css
.callback {
  position: relative;
}

.city-menu {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.callback a:hover + .city-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="callback">
  <div>Ваш город:

    <br><a href="#">Киев</a>
    <div class="city-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Киев</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```